# Zend - Moving from reCaptcha to reCaptcha2

Tags: php, zend-framework, recaptcha

I currently have a Recaptcha form on my site, which uses Zend. What do I need to change here to implement Recaptcha2?

```
$reCaptcha = new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha($config->recaptcha->site_key, $config->recaptcha->secret_key);

    $captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha',
        array(
            'captcha'       => 'ReCaptcha',
            'captchaOptions' => array(
                'captcha' => 'ReCaptcha',
                'service' => $reCaptcha,
                'messages' => array(
                    'badCaptcha' => $translator->translate('Form-Captcha-InvalidCaptchaValue')
                ),
                'theme' => 'white'
            ),
            'ignore' => true,
        )
    );
```

Thanksr

Comment: See https://packagist.org/packages/cgsmith/zf1-recaptcha-2